# Is there formal guidance on when equations should be aligned at the equals sign?

Tags: notation

There are plenty of resources out there explaining *how* to align multiple lines of equations at the equals sign. But I can’t find anything that says *when* this should be done. Does any style guide, ISO standard, or similar publication address this?

Use cases I’ve seen include:

1. One equation spanning multiple lines, e.g.
   $$
   \begin{align}
   0 &= x^2 - 4x + 4 \\
     &= (x - 2)^2
   \end{align}
   $$
2. The next line is derived from the previous one, e.g.
   $$
   \begin{align}
   0 &= (x - 2)^2 \\
   \therefore x &= 2
   \end{align}
   $$
3. The equations are a list of formulas, identities, etc. given together, e.g.
   $$
   \begin{align}
   d &= 2r \\
   C &= 2\pi r \\
   \mathrm{Area} &= \pi r^2
   \end{align}
   $$
4. The lines are a system of equations, to be solved or otherwise treated together, e.g.
   $$
   \begin{align}
   2x &+ 4y &= 4 \\
   x &+ y &= 3
   \end{align}
   $$

(I would think that #3 is done because it looks tidy, whereas #1 and #2 are about *continuity* between lines, and #4 is more general related-ness. But that’s just my impression.)

I’m intentionally leaving out *in*equalities, by the way. They have [their own issues](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3572541/160630).

Comment: I would broadened your third category to systems of equations or *inequalities*.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. I've gotten away with writing something like $\text{something} = \text{other thing} = \text{this thing} = \text{that thing}$ in one begin-align environment on my assignments. If I find a line of equalities to have a lot of steps, I use the & signs to line up my equal signs.

Comment: @hardmath I’m adding systems of equations as its own category. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If ISO can tell us [we should be using roman d, not italic, for differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000), it won’t surprise me in the least if they have something on when to align equals signs!

Comment: I’d be interested to discuss the reasons for closing this as *opinion-based*. It’s not my intention to ask for anyone’s opinion on when they think equals signs should be aligned, nor even for anecdotal evidence of when they do see them aligned. I want to know of the **factual existence of guidelines** produced by any relevant organisation or body. I edited the question to remove anything I could find that I thought might be construed otherwise, but the response was simply that the issue was “not resolved”.